# How to know when my Activity is fully created?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I've an Activity that contains a lot of data and elements.

When it has too information, the **activity wait in white** for be shown, that is not I want, I actually want to **show a activity while it's loading the data**.

So, How can I to know when my activity it's fully created?

My intention is to launch in a second thread the activity across the waiting activity.

Comment: what kind of data your activity has to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AsyncTask and can show progress dialog till the data is loaded.

```
private class FetchRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

  private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(
            R.string.Loading_String));
    this.dialog.show();
  }

protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
    try {

        // Fetch the data from URL
        // do background process

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", "error", e);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (success) {
        // Setting data to list adaptar
        setListData();
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can not use this while on main UI

Answer (score 3):

You should load that data asynchronously, in another thread if it takes that much time to load. Launch another thread (by using an AsyncTask for example of plain Java Threads), load the data and show some loading-View on the Activity that notifies the user that something is happening in the background.

Answer (score 2):

This method called after on create in activity

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
}
```